# select * where not in (other table values)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a `reserves` table like this:

| id | name | room_ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | B | 2,3,4 |
| 3 | B | 2,4,5 |

And `rooms` table like this:

| id | room name | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | room a | 1 |
| 2 | room b | 2 |
| 3 | room c | 1 |
| 4 | room e | 3 |
| 5 | room f | 1 |
| 6 | room g | 2 |
| 7 | room h | 2 |

Is it possible to get rooms with ids not in column `room_ids` in the `reserves` table with a single query? Something like: `Select * from rooms where id not in (select room_ids from reserves)`.

Comment: *Is it possible to get rooms with ids not in column room_ids in the reserves table with a single query?* Yes. Parse to separate ID values then join. *I think it will be the same in every other SQL database.* NO. Each DBMS have its own functions.

Comment: @Akina basically it's doable with a single function, namely `concat`. If we prepend and append a `,` to `room_ids`, then we can use the `like` operator to check whether this contains `,<the id>,`.

Comment: `room_ids` has a format that violates even 1NF. It would be a good idea to separate `room_ids` into its own table and then the tasks related to it will be much easier. I have provided a solution for this particular format, but if you do not refactor your schema, then you overcomplicate your task.

Comment: @LajosArpad This is too slow. Parsing will be more fast, especially on huge data arrays.

Comment: @Akina have you performed tests?

Comment: @LajosArpad, yes I can separate, but when there are thousands of reserves, rows in the new table become much more. And it slows down a lot.

Comment: @sdeav I understand what you say, but have you tested my suggestion? Was it slow?

Comment: @LajosArpad. Yes, I have created another table only with `reserve_id` and `room_id` then joined. And it was slower than doing it like in my example but with two queries. First, got all reserved room ids, then second with `where not in ()`.

Comment: @sdeav my understanding was that the problem was that you wanted to solve this with a single query. Now I understand that the actual problem that you have is more related to performance.

Comment: @sdeav basically you can use some parsing, like Akina suggested and that may be quicker, but the problem in reality is more fundamental. Your `room_ids` contains repetitive data and you will always have difficulties filtering it, updating it and managing it in general. I would move this property out from `reserves` into its own table, where each record you would have would represent a reserved room, so you would have a room id and a reservation id.

Comment: @LajosArpad. Only for this situation, I don't need to update or manage it. I just needed to get the result in the fastest way possible. I thought using 1 query would be fast. But, using 2 queries is faster than using the normalized version. So I used that. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @sdeav my query is not a normalized version. It is a way of handling the not normalized table. Normalizing your table would involve the creation of a new table, like I suggested. "Only for this situation, I don't need to update or manage it." somehow those record ended up being stored in your database. That means that a write operation, like an insert or update ended up with the result of your composite values and the not normalized nature of your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
select rooms.*
from rooms
left join reserves
on concat(',', room_ids, ',') like concat('%,', rooms.id, ',%')
where reserves.id is null
```

Explanation:

- `left join` yields at least one pair for each record of `rooms`
- if `rooms` does not have a valid pair, then the `reserves` values will be nulls
- so, in the `where` clause we check for `null` being the value of some not nullable `reserves` field
- which ensures that we exclude any `rooms` that have any existing reservations

EDIT

If the problem is performance, then it would make sense to refactor the schema, create a new table called `room_reservation(room_id, reservation_id)`, move the `room_ids` property's content out from `reservations` into this new table and perform a `left join`. Your main problem is that the current schema's plan has some flaws that you need to fix if you do not want to get into problems intermittently.